# How can I determine which version of MacOS I'm compiling on?

Tags: c++, macos, compilation, cross-platform

I'm compiling conditionally:

```
#ifdef WIN32
  myVal = "Windows";
#elif __APPLE__
  myVal = "Apple";
#endif
```

Is there a value I can test within the `__APPLE__` block to test against different versions (10.4,10.5,10.6 etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to check the compiler's environment, try `uname -v`.

Specifically, I think you can do `uname -v | sed 's/Darwin Kernel Version \([^ ]*\):.*/\1/'` to get, e.g. "10.5".

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h` macros. See [TN2064](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2064/_index.html) for discussion, as well as the header comments in this file.

Comment: This doesn't look like what I want, these are settings set by the developer, I want to know the OS of the machine it's running on.

Comment: But @Tom, your question demonstrates detecting the OS of the machine *your compiler* is running on. You're checking compile-time macros. If you want the run-time OS version, then you need to write code that will be evaluated at run time, so `#ifdef` is off the table entirely. So, please clarify your question: Do you want to check the compiler's environment, or the program's?

Comment: Compiler's, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: So, this gives you what the developer requested on the machine that it is compiling on. Isn't that what you wanted? Asking for the actual machine OS isn't very useful if the developer requested a different SDK.